Is this story of John Wesley, a horse, and a bridge true?
I recently heard a story about John Wesley giving way to a stubborn man while on a narrow bridge: in short, Wesley was riding his horse on a bridge, while a man who was known to be a critic of Wesley was riding the other way. The bridge was too narrow for both, so the man said, "I never make way for a fool!" Wesley responded, "I do", and backed his horse out so the man can cross.
This was interesting, so I decided to look it up. However, no matter the keywords I used, I was never able to find it. The closest that I was able to find is ChristianCentury.org, but it was a road, not a bridge; additionally, it was the only reference to that particular story I could find. (Update: I also found another reference here, thanks to using the phrase "I never make way for a fool Wesley")
In a moment of desperation, I turned to LLMs --- since they have been trained on a lot of text, maybe they are able to retrieve something that I missed.
I used labs.perplexity.com and used Llama-70b and Nemotron-340b with this prompt:

What's that story about John Wesley on a horse crossing a narrow bridge?

To my surprise, both LLMs were able to produce the exact story (this was yesterday; I couldn't reproduce it today while writing this question), so maybe this story was written somewhere, even if it's just apocryphal?

Did they walk into a bar???

@JonCuster With a priest and a rabbit.

Google Books finds an 1874 cite (https://books.google.com/books?id=YFlNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA172&dq=%22%22I+never+make+way+for+a+fool%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjozL_Cp8qHAxWgKlkFHcW1PHUQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22%22I%20never%20make%20way%20for%20a%20fool%22&f=false) and an 1855 one with Swift not Wesley. (https://books.google.com/books?id=awBhXZd313sC&pg=PA522&dq=%22%22I+never+make+way+for+a+fool%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjozL_Cp8qHAxWgKlkFHcW1PHUQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22%22I%20never%20make%20way%20for%20a%20fool%22&f=false)

Google books finds this 1843 instance: https://books.google.com/books?id=q_cDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA518&dq=%22%22I+never+make+way+for+a+fool%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixye-wqMqHAxU4FFkFHW27BEYQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22%22I%20never%20make%20way%20for%20a%20fool%22&f=false

Funny thing is, I was just this morning thinking about an old John Wesley joke question that got posted here years ago (trying to remember the exact joke), and then this gets posted. It was this question, posted here 9 years ago. I think its pretty clear this was just another John Wesley joke like that one, and thus unlikely to be biographically true (while perhaps being quite biographically revealing)

Huh, I heard the story with John Randolph, on a narrow sidewalk in DC, not a bridge.

Stories like this are almost never true. It's such a good story, anyone hearing it is going to embellish it to make it even better next time it is told. It doesn't have to be true to achieve its purpose, so why would anyone telling the tale take any care to verify it?

An example of this story featuring Wesley appears in the 1907 book of "The World's Best Humorous Anecdotes" - which does not lead me to believe that this particular story is historically accurate.

In 1855 the phrase was attributed to the Dean of St. Patrick's Cathedral, one Jonathan Swift. Even this may be apocryphal, as Swift died in 1745, over a century before this witticism was attributed to him.

(Updated with a reference from the comments): The story is also quoted in the Wesleyan-Methodist Magazine in 1843, meaning that a reference to Wesley predates the one to Swift:

Wesley and "Beau" Nash were documented to clash, as a Methodist preacher and a dandy would hardly be expected to get along, and their prominence in the town of Bath would have brought them together on occasions despite their mutual dislike - which perhaps explains his retroactive addition to the tale.

The earliest version I could find with Google Books is a passage in the 1843 The Wesleyan-Methodist Magazine, p518.  The earliest version with a bridge is the 1927 book  Israel in Prophecy and History  by P.W.Thompson, p 182.

How did you find this?! I didn't think of searching of searching Google Books directly, but that should have popped up during my initial search, right?

@DrownedSuccess I asked GB for the quoted string "I never make way for a fool" and the date range up to 1850, and then also added in the search term "bridge" with a 19th century date range.  I think vanilla google search does not look into book contents as much as GB does.

@kimchilover : this means that in case this really happened, it was more likely just on a narrow path, not a bridge, as the bridge was added much later to the story.
